# Thinkpad update issue

Tags: updates, lenovo, firmware

I've just installed Ubuntu and started receiving update prompts. I see these two updates in the popup. When I click the update button, it tells me it cannot find the cab file in the archive. (Please see image for better details.)

[image: Image: Updating firmware missing archive]